# Running VBA set on formula cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code (below) to hide and show rows based on a cell value, the VBA works when the cell is clicked in and then out however or done manually however there is a formula in the cell i need the VBA to be based on and I have tried a couple of ways but I am not getting any success and cannot get it to refresh and run the VBA. I don't really want or need to have the end user to click in any unnecessary fields  - any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 ActiveSheet.Activate
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 On Error Resume Next
 If Not Application.Intersect(Range("G20"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value

    Case Is = "0":
    Rows("27:64").EntireRow.Hidden = True


    End Select

    End If

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("G20"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value

    Case Is = "1":
                        Rows("27:29").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("31:42").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("52:64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("43:45").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("46:51").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("30:30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select

   If
   On Error Resume Next
   If Not Application.Intersect(Range("G20"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value

    Case Is = "2":
                        Rows("27:29").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("31:45").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("52:64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("46:51").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("30:30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select

  End If
  On Error Resume Next
  If Not Application.Intersect(Range("G20"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value

    Case Is = "3":
                        Rows("27:31").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("31:42").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("46:51").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("43:45").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End Select

 End If
 On Error Resume Next
  If Not Application.Intersect(Range("G20"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value

    Case Is = "4":
                        Rows("27:31").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                        Rows("32:45").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("52:64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("46:51").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select

 End If

 On Error Resume Next
 If Not Application.Intersect(Range("G20"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value

    Case Is = "5":
     Rows("27:64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Change your event from `Worksheet_Change` to `Worksheet_Calculate`. You use Calculate when you need it to trigger after some formula updates a cell.

Comment: Hi I changed the event to Worksheet_Calculate but now have a compile error.

Comment: Which is weird because you have a lot of `On Error Resume Next`. Where is your error? Which line? And please, get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` they hide potential errors.

Comment: The On Error Resume Next have been removed, the error is on the Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal Target As Range)

Comment: Sorry, `Worksheet_Calculate()` it doesn't have a target, triggers everytime the Worksheet is recalculated.

Comment: The code now shows opening as Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate() however the error now occurs - on the first if not... runtime error 424

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213165/discussion-between-fordy-and-damian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna assume you are checking the cell `G20`in order to hide/unhide rows. So we are going to do this:

First change the code in your worksheet object for this:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    HideRows Me.Range("G20"), Me

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

This will call another procedure which will be contained in a module like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub HideRows(CellValue As Long, ws As Worksheet)

    With ws
        Select Case CellValue
            Case 0
                .Rows("27:64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case 1
                .Rows("27:29").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                .Rows("31:42").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                .Rows("52:64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                .Rows("43:45").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                .Rows("46:51").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                .Rows("30:30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case 2
                .Rows("27:29").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                .Rows("31:45").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                .Rows("52:64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                .Rows("46:51").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                .Rows("30:30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case 3
                .Rows("27:31").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                .Rows("31:42").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                .Rows("46:51").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                .Rows("43:45").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case 4
                .Rows("27:31").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                .Rows("32:45").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                .Rows("52:64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                .Rows("46:51").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case 5
                .Rows("27:64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End Select
    End With

End Sub
```

This way you can use the code for multiple worksheets if they are build the same way, you will only need to copy the code from the worksheet object to other worksheets and it will cal the `HideRows` which will then hide/unhide rows depending on the value of the cell `G20` you can change the target on every sheet.

And as for the use of `Select Case` you can see that you only need one with all your cases for the value.